# Adding multiple namespace in XML using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<application xmlns="http://someurl">
    <Detail1/>
    <Detail2>
    <Property/>
    </Detail2>
</application>
```

I am trying to add `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` and `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` to the "application root node". I tried to follow a lot of links on stackoverflow but nothing seemed to work in XSLT 1.0
Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 3):

Since XSLT 1.0 doesn't have the `<xsl:namespace>` instruction in XSLT 2.0, the technique I use is to copy such nodes from my stylesheet:

Input:

```
t:\ftemp>type ns.xml
  <application xmlns="http://someurl">
    <Detail1/>
    <Detail2>
    <Property/>
    </Detail2>
</application>
```

Execution:

```
t:\ftemp>call xslt ns.xml ns.xsl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><application xmlns="http://someurl" xmlns:
xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchem
a-instance">
    <Detail1/>
    <Detail2>
    <Property/>
    </Detail2>
</application>
```

Stylesheet:

```
t:\ftemp>type ns.xsl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="document('')/*/namespace::xs"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="document('')/*/namespace::xsi"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()"><!--identity for all other nodes-->
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
t:\ftemp>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. As i am new to xslt can you help me what does the below lines means:
<xsl:copy-of select="document('')/*/namespace::xs"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="document('')/*/namespace::xsi"/> 

I tried to run the code in the below tool, but showing me the original xml only. 
http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php

Comment: I indicated in my answer that I am copying the namespace nodes from the stylesheet using those instructions.  My transcript shows the stylesheet is working with a conforming XSLT processor.  If the stylesheet does not work for you, then you have a problem somewhere in your environment.  I cannot tell you what is wrong with your environment.